# Apache Virtualhosts, stopping PHP throwing errors with "/"

Tags: php, apache

I have a pretty stable development machine set up running Apache and using virtual hosts to keep my projects separate, and running a dyndns.org service which I use to access them.  Each VHost directive typically looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [my_internal_subdomain].[my_dyndns_name].dyndns.org
    ServerAlias home

    DocumentRoot "D:/webserver/[projectDirectory]/httpdocs"
    php_admin_value open_basedir "c:/WINDOWS/TEMP;D:/webserver/[projectDirectory]/"

    ErrorLog "D:/webserver/[projectDirectory]/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "D:/webserver/[projectDirectory]/logs/access.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously [projectDirectory], [my_internal_subdomain] and [my_dyndns_name] are all values I know/change for each directive, just no need to post them here :)

One thing has always confounded me however, in PHP, if I want to require a file from say /includes/, I would expect to use:

```
require("/includes/myfile.php");
```

Except doing so throws an open_basedir restriction error - because "/" is trying to go, presumably to the root of D:/ - whereas I would like each virtual host to recognise that the value of DocumentRoot is in fact where I would like PHP to go if I call a file by "/".

This is how my production server seems to work, and its a bit of a pain having to code everything to work out what the relative path to /includes/ is for the benefit of my dev machine.

I expect this is a fairly simple/obvious directive I'm missing but I can't find it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.  To clarify, I do presently use a PHP based method similar to those suggested to include files from the right path, but I figured there had to be a better way.  I'm Pretty sure "/" works on my production server (which was configured by my service provider and administered using Plesk), but that runs linux, and probably has the vhosts jailed as I provide shared hosting on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/myfile.php');
```

Comment: Yeah, except I really dislike having to type that every time! :)

Comment: Well... If you don't like setting absolute paths, then set relative paths. And if you don't like settings paths, try include_path or class autoloading. I can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish with Apache.

Comment: I was just trying to remove the need to make PHP think about where the files were every time someone hits a page, i'm sure its barely measurable in terms of processing time - but it seems silly to have to do it.  Absolute paths are a problem when moving from one server to another which has a different filesystem.   I just changed to a class autoloader the other day, first time I have used one but I am realising the benefits - it might be that I use your solution in conjunction with that.

Comment: File system functions don't need any information from Apache that they can't grab themselves. Actually, they don't even need a web server at all.

Comment: I just rolled out the class autoloader into the project and its cut down the list of requires to a far less annoying level, and meant I only really need to specify the path after document root once, rather than for each one.  It's much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`require` paths takes filesystem paths so "/" will always be the root of the filesystem OR paths that relate to your `include_path` setting. You can change your includes slightly and set the include path like this to get around it:

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'D:/.../httpdocs');
require('includes/myfile.php');
```

This will work because it will find the `includes` folder in your `include_path`.

Comment: I'd not changed the include path in the vhost set up too much because I need/want my dev machine to resemble my live machine as much as possible to prevent code not working when I upload.  I hadn't thought of setting the value at runtime - i'll take that under consideration, thanks!

Comment: You could also combine with the answer about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as well (use that to set the path instead of specifying it manually). But it is a good point that this requires setting a path for your given environment!

Comment: Yup, i've gone with the document root and class autoload solution.  I'm a huge fan of being able to upload to a new server without having to remember to reconfigure settings - so I make efforts to put in place logic that ensures the right paths, db connection variables, admin email addresses etc are used depending on which machine the code finds itself.  I have lost count of the number of times before I did that that I changed a config file, and uploaded it with test server credentials and killed a whole site for a couple of minutes :-)

Answer (score 0):

PHP by itself has no real concept of a DocumentRoot for its file-related functions. It seems only the file system of the server. The whole DocumentRoot business is something applied at the webserver layer.

If you want to use `require('/....')` in your code, you'd need to use mod_chroot (or mod_security's chroot functionality), so you can "jail" each vhost into its own directory tree, and make the `/` directory be whatever you want for each one.

However, chrooting has its own problems - it would lock off the rest of the file system. If your script exec()'s something  externally, or connects to MySQL, or does anything on the filesystem, you'd need to have copies of those executables, .so libraries, MySQL socket file, etc... within the jail.

Comment: I guess chroot is what my production server (which I didnt set up) uses as I provide shared hosting so locking off the file system is exactly the right thing to do.  All the extra config to do that on my dev machine though could just be annoying, since I don't really need to worry about securing all the projects filesystems from each other...!  Looks like this is why I can get away with "/" on my production machine.

Answer (score 0):

In linux it's more common to have a 'chrooted' environment then in windows. You may determine your root by setting a configuration directive from a file in your root and get the directory name like this

```
$dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
// or however you wish to arrange your affairs.
$myConfigObject->set('root',$dirname);
```

Edit: This approach does not nescesairly use the document root, however I find that in many cases I will have multiple instances of the same project, and that most of my php files will be outside the document root for security reasons.

It will be something along the lines of this:

```
/home/dir         (project root
/home/dir/stable (project instance root)
/home/dir/dev    (project instance root2)
/home/dir/stable/lib    (php files)
/home/dir/stable/web    (webroot)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this one will work for me, I use a number of includes/requires and a common 'init' file that loads them it, and the file loading the init file can be on the root, or in a directory, or subdirectory etc - so the file can be a moving target, relatively speaking - which is why i was looking to use a very absolute "/" (and no explicit directory names that differ from server to server and I will forget to change when I upload changes).

Comment: Ah, ok. For me it's more or less the same, but you can see that there is always an relative path to the library for each project. That one is an 'absolute' relative path.

Comment: Yep, my problem is mainly with the requires that happen in the init, because that is itself an included file, and PHP tries to do all the requires based on the directory of the original file, not the init file.  I have code that works it out, but it just didn't seem as though it should be necessary to make PHP have to work out where to load these files from every time someone hits a page :-)